# Is there a way to script repetitive tasks in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

We have a number of tasks that we carry out every time we create a new GIT repository in our project, and I would like to know if there's a way to script (PowerShell or any other method) these out. for e.g. every these are the steps we follow everytime we create a new repo

1. Create a new GIT repo
2. Create a Build pipeline for Build validations during
   pull request
3. Add branch policies to Master including a step to validate build using the above build
4. Create a Build pipeline for releases
5. Create a Release pipeline

Comment: Yes. Look at the REST API documentation.

Comment: Hi, how the things going now? Does the answer below has any help for you? If yes, you can accept that thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can still help you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to script repetitive tasks in Azure DevOps?

Of course yes! As Daniel said in comment, just use REST API can achieve these all. But since the steps you want to achieve are little much, the script might be little **complex**.

---

- Create a new GIT repo

If you also want to use API to finish this step, it needs 3 steps to finish that( Since this does not be documented in doc, I will described it very detailed ):

**Step1**: Create the validation of importing repository

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/git/import/ImportRepositoryValidations?api-version=5.2-preview.1
```

Request body:

```
{
  "gitSource":
     {
      "url":"${ReposURL}",
      "overwrite":false
     },
    "tfvcSource":null,
    "username":"$(username}"/null,
    "password":"${pw}"/"${PAT}"/null
}
```

**Step2**: Create the new repos name

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/git/Repositories?api-version=5.2-preview.1
```

Request body:

```
{
  "name":"${ReposName}",
  "project":
  {
    "name":"{project name}",
    "id":"{this project id}"
  }
}
```

**Step3**: Import repos

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{the new repos name you create just now}/importRequests?api-version=5.2-preview.1
```

Request body:

```
{
  "parameters":
  {
   "deleteServiceEndpointAfterImportIsDone":true,
   "gitSource":
    {
     "url":"${ReposURL}",
     "overwrite":false
    },
    "tfvcSource":null,
    "serviceEndpointId":null
}
}
```

In these script, you can set variables in **Variable** tab, then use `${}` to get them in the script.

---

- Create a Build pipeline for Build validations during pull request

This step you'd better finish manually, because you can configure more about tasks and trigger with UI. If still want use API, refer to this doc: [create build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1). There has detailed sample you can try with.

---

Add branch policies to Master including a step to validate build using the above build

This API still be documented in doc: [create build policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#build-policy). Just refer to that, and ensure use the correct `policy type` and the corresponding `buildDefinitionId`.

---

- Create a Build pipeline for releases

This still recommend you finish manually, same with the step3 you mentioned.

---

Create a Release pipeline

See this doc: [create release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

**Note:** For some parameter which will be used many times, you can set it as variable. For the parameter which need get from previous API response, you can define a variable to get its value then pass this variable into the next API to use.For e.g. :

```
$resultT= $result.Headers.ETag
Write-Host  "##vso[task.setvariable variable=etag;]$resultT"
```

Now, you can directly use the `$(etag)` in the next API.