# Auto copy in azure repo from bitbucket repo

Tags: git, azure, merge, azure-devops, azure-repos

Is it possible to make automatic synchronization of repositories, for example through pipline?
I have 5 repositories Azure DevOps
Which should be exactly the same as in Bitbucket (work in Bitbucket)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Auto copy in azure repo from bitbucket repo

Yes, we could use the Azure pipeline to sync Azure devops git repo with bitbucket repo.

Add a powershell task to execute the git command line to sync the changes:

```
git remote add bitbucket https://Username:password@bitbucket.org/xxx/xxxx.git HEAD:master
git checkout $branch
git push bitbucket $branch -f
```

Besides, we could also enable the continuous integration for the pipeline, so that there is any changes in the Azure repo, it will synchronizes the changes to the bitbucket repo.

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874462/how-to-sync-repo-in-bitbucket-to-visual-studio-team-service) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62990634/receiving-fatal-not-a-git-repository-or-any-of-the-parent-directories-git/63006319#63006319) for some more details.

Comment: thank you very much, I will study all info.
There is a problem that these repositories already have azure.yml
and some use Linux, it's not clear how to make another pipeline and use powershell

Comment: oh. i can use one new pipline (and new repo) to sync all 5 repo?

Comment: @Сергейtoff, Yes, you could so that. Just create a new folder and use git clone command line to clone all 5repo one by one, then sync it to the bitbucket repo.

Comment: Are it way is bad? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57908569/is-there-a-way-to-script-repetitive-tasks-in-azure-devops 
Rest post for auto import?